Sulfone charge density and structure
when we think of sulfone structure such as R2-S-O2 which is more reasonable strcuture?
two double bonds between sulfur and oxygens or one single bond and one double bond with formal charge +1 on S and -1 on single bonded oxygen?

Neither. $\ce{ }$

then what's the correct structure?

Two dative bonds. And formal charge hardly has much to do with charge density.

I'd go for all single bonds and charge separation, but that's only one way. There are more.
